# How to avoid overflow in python when numerator and denominator are both large

Tags: python, integer-overflow

```
from operator import mul    
from fractions import Fraction
import math

n = 5000

def nCk(n,k): 
  return int( reduce(mul, (Fraction(n-i, i+1) for i in range(k)), 1) )

p = 2.884e-5
totP = 0
sgn = 1

print "n: " + str(n)
for r in range(1, n):
    numTerms = nCk(n,r) - ((2*n-3)*(r-1))
    totP += sgn * (p ** r) * numTerms
    sgn *= -1

print "total = " + str(totP)
```

I'm getting an overflow error when I start increasing n: OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float

the `numTerms` term gets very large while the`p^r` term gets very small.  Basically, I have a large numerator dividing a large denominator.  Any suggestions on how to compute this?  I've thought about using logarithms and Stirling's approximation formula for n! to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If you can tolerate a very slight loss of precision, you can use logarithms to avoid the division step altogether. By definition, `a/b` equals `exp(log(a)-log(b))`. This works over a very wide range of inputs without over- or underflow.

To put this in the context of your original code -- you had:

```
return int( reduce(mul, (Fraction(n-i, i+1) for i in range(k)), 1) )
```

The substitutions you want to apply are:

```
[1] a*b --> exp(log(a)+log(b))
[2] c/d --> exp(log(c)-log(d))
```

So I believe your recast function would look like this:

```
from operator import add
from math import exp, log
...

return int( exp(reduce(add, (log(n-i)-log(i+1) for i in range(k)), 1)) )
```

Comment: I was trying to do something like that but not sure how to modify my code to do that trick.  Would I put that in line 16 in totP calculation or embed it inside nCk function somehow when computing n!/(n-r)!r! ?

Comment: See my revised answer above.

Answer (score 1):

To handle large precision, you can use the `decimal` library:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100 #Or whatever precision you want...
...
p = decimal.Decimal(2.884e-5)
...
```

The code is pretty slow though, it hasn't stopped on my computer...

Finally got done, and realized: you print out `str(p)`, and you never change it... Maybe you meant `totP`?

Comment: Yea, sorry, I edited my code slightly before pasting in. I'm interested in totP.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using scipy.misc.comb function and setting a ceiling when the float value reached 'Inf'.